# How do I add a row of data to specific columns?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV named `test.csv`, whose headers look like this:

```
"Fruit","Weight","Color"
```

In my ruby script, I have an array that looks like this:

```
["Banana","Yellow"]
```

How do I use Ruby's `csv` class to put `"Banana"` in column `"Fruit"` and `"Yellow"` in column `"Color"`?

Comment: `CSV` is a class distributed with Ruby, loaded with `require 'csv'`. I expect there  are CSV gems, but you're probably referring to the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  fruit, color = ["Banana","Yellow"]
  csv << [fruit, nil, color]
end
```

And if you have multiple rows with the same structure:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  rows.each do |row|
    # Assuming row looks like ["Banana", "Yellow"]
    fruit, color = row
    csv << [fruit, nil, color]
  end
end
```

And if in your real life example your arrays have many more columns (not just two) and you want to add a few empty columns sporadically, you can use the [Array#insert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) method:

```
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  rows.each do |row|
    # Run one line like this for every empty column you want to add
    # Note that it changes the value of `row`, so if you'd like to 
    # keep it untouched, consider using `dup`
    row.insert(1, nil)
    csv << row
  end
end
```